# Select rows until value changes

Tags: sqlite, select, row, limit

I have an SQLite table where I know that all rows are grouped such that all values in the first column occur in a block:

```
A ...
A ...
A ...
C ...
B ...
B ...
D ...
D ...
```

Starting at one row, I would like to select only the next rows until the value of the first column changes.

I.e. starting at row 1, I would get:

```
A ...
A ...
A ...
```

The important part here is to not look any further in order to save processing time. Of course indexing the column is an option, but an expensive one.

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. To get all `A` rows, simply use `WHERE Col1 = 'A'`, but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok I guess theoretically they are unordered, practically in my case the 'arbitrary' order is that of insertion and that is an orderly order...